# Vs code, devcontainer, git

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, containers, wsl-2

I keep getting this error `error: unable to unlink old`, when I change something on other device and then try to `pull`.

Unfortunately `sudo chmod -R g+w` doesn't help, even option with `a` didnt fix it.

Is there a way to make my git user able to do whatever changes it wants on dirs shared with docker containers (because now I have to `sudo rm -rf` (yes sudo, because normal gives permission error) folder and clone again ...)?

Comment: please add more info. Where are you trying to do chmod? was are you trying to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this is a handle resource issue as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199888/6309), and explained in "[Git on WSL: error: unable to unlink old  Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56961355/6309)"

Close VSCode (or even reboot), and try the `git pull` command in your WSL session (again, with VSCode closed).

Then reopen VSCode, which will [use the `/mnt/c` WSL mounted path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl).

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/remote/wsl/architecture-wsl.png]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not a rights issue but another application has locked the file. Try closing all your applications and pull again.